# Get Palette Contrast Hue Based on Current Theme

Tags: angular-material2

I have the following palettes, with various hue values, being applied to multiple themes in my `material-theme.scss` file:

```
$green: mat-palette($mat-green, A400);
$blue: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A400);
$red: mat-palette($mat-red);
$red-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, A100);
```

In my `material-styles.scss` file, I have a mixin that is used to define styles based on the current theme:

```
@mixin style-theme($theme) {
  $p: map-get($theme, primary);
  $a: map-get($theme, accent);
  $w: map-get($theme, warn);
  $primary: mat-color($p);
  $accent: mat-color($a);
  $warn: mat-color($w);
  $primary-contrast: mat-contrast($p, 500);
  $accent-contrast: mat-contrast($a, 500);
  $warn-contrast: mat-contrast($w, 500);

  // Apply styling based on values above
}
```

Themes are created as follows:

```
.light-green {
    $default-theme: mat-light-theme($green, $blue);
    @include style-theme($default-theme);
    @include angular-material-theme($default-theme);
}
```

Is it possible for me to get the contrast of the currently applied palette? As it is now, I am only able to hard-code the `$hue` value for the `mat-contrast` function.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-contrast-hue?file=app%2Ftheme%2Fmaterial-theme.scss)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are six 'special' keys that are automatically added to a palette when you use `mat-palette()`:

```
default
lighter
darker
default-contrast
lighter-contrast
darker-contrast
```

Each base palette contains all of the colors mapped to the keys 50, 100, ... 900, A100, A200, A400, A700. It also contains a sub-palette mapped to the key 'contrast' with a set of contrast colors mapped to the same keys. The colors assigned to the special keys correspond to the hue values passed in to `mat-palette()`, which default to 500, 100, and 700 respectively for default, lighter, and darker. The '*-contrast' mapped colors are pulled from the contrast sub-palette using the same hue value keys.

When you call `mat-color()` without a hue key it uses `default` as the key. But you could use any of the special keys so that you don't need to know which hue values are actually mapped to the special keys.

So for example, you could call `mat-color($green, default-contrast)` to get the proper contrast color for the default color in your green palette.

Comment: I literally just figured this out, but am marking yours as the answer for your efforts. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure it out by inspecting the theming for [MatToolbar](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6.0.x/src/lib/toolbar/_toolbar-theme.scss#L8).

You can get the contrast color value for a palette using the following:

```
$contrast: mat-color($palette, default-contrast);
```

See revised [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-contrast-hue?file=app%2Ftheme%2Fmaterial-styles.scss)